# die schöne alte Stadt und die schöne, alte Stadt -- semantischer Unterschied oder einfach falsche Kommasetzung?

Tags: punctuation

Ein Komma soll zwischen gleichrangigen Adjektiven gesetzt werden, die einen aufzählenden Charakter haben, jedoch nicht zwischen  Adjektiven, bei denen eine "feste" Verbindung zwischen Substantiv und Adjektiv besteht.

Meine Frage ist nun, ob damit auch Unterschiede im gemeinten Inhalt sichtbar gemacht werden können.

> Die Stadt ist sowohl schön als auch alt -> die schöne, alte Stadt; die alte, schöne Stadt

> Die schöne Stadt ist alt. -> die alte schöne Stadt

> Die alte Stadt ist schön. -> die schöne alte Stadt; die schöne Altstadt

Was sagt ihr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im ersten Absatz ist eigentlich schon alles Wesentliche gesagt.

*Schöne, alte Stadt* kann man verwenden, wenn auch ohne nähere Bezeichnung klar ist, um welche Stadt es geht und diese Stadt alt und außerdem schön ist.

Wenn dagegen *alt* dazu dient, eine bestimmte Stadt zu bezeichnen, muss das Komma weggelassen werden:

> Die schöne alte Stadt und die häßliche neue Stadt

Nebenmei bemerkt: *Alte Stadt* und *Altstadt* sind keine Synonyme.

Comment: Hast Du dafür einen Beleg? Kommt mir falsch vor. Etwas anderes wären feststehende Ausdrücke wie die fette Beute. M.E. kann man Entscheidungskriterium heranziehen, ob man die Reihenfolge der Adjektive umkehren könnte. Wenn ja, gehört ein Komma dazwischen.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist meiner Kenntnis nach richtig analysiert. Hier wird kein Komma gesetzt, wenn Attribute aufgezählt werden, die das Substantiv treffen.

Ganz verstanden habe ich das aber noch nie. Ähnlich wie @UserUnknown sagt und auch deine Eingangserläuterung andeutet, sind Aufzählungen unter Umständen dem Gefühl nach zu trennen. Dafür ließen sich die zu trennenden Phrasen sicherlich grammatikalisch je nach Typ unterscheiden, ob adverbial als Verb-Komplement, adjektivisch oder partizipativ.

Behelfsweise kann man sich einreden es bestehe wie im Englischen eine feste Reihenfolge von inneinandergreifenden adjektiven, die, weil Sie einander modifizieren, deshalb nicht vertauscht werden können ohne potentiell Stilblüten zu generieren (beim großen grünen Drachen ist natürlich besonders viel Grün zu sehen, dagegen ist seine Größe nicht unbedingt grün).

Einfacher gesagt, kann man veruschen, das vermeintliche Komma durch eine Konjunktion zu ersetzen, etwa durch Und. Vgl. *Der gemietete schnelle und rote Wagen*. *?Der gemietete und schnelle rote Wagen*. (citation needed)

---

### Schöne Alt-Stadt

<sup>Das Beispiel von @RHa lässt sich modifizieren, um den Fall zu verdeutlichen</sup>

> *Schöne, alte Stadt* kann man verwenden, wenn auch ohne nähere Bezeichnung klar ist, um welche Stadt es geht und diese Stadt alt und außerdem schön ist.

> Wenn dagegen *alt* dazu dient, eine bestimmte Stadt zu bezeichnen, muss das Komma weggelassen werden:

Das interpretiere ich folgender Maßen

> Das schöne alte Hamburg (das man nur noch aus Erinnerungen kennt)

Dies steht Gegensatz zum modernen Hamburg, das auch schön sein mag. Darüber wollen wir aber keine Aussage treffen. Auch wollen wir nicht behaupten, das heutige Hamburg sei alt, denn dann stünden *Moderne* und *Altertum* im Widerspruch zueinander.

In einer anderen Bedeutung ist es aber doch alt:

> Das alte moderne Hamburg (hundert Jahre hat es auf dem Buckel)

Daraus wird dann fix

> Das schöne, alte moderne Hamburg

Bezeichnender Weise ist *modernes Hamburg* kein feststehender Eigenname. Der etwaige Titel "modern" kann also leicht abgetrennt werden (und zur Veranschaulichung umgedeutet):

> Das schöne, alte, modernisierte Hamburg

Bei *alte Stadt* soll das laut @RHa gewisser Maßen ähnlich sein. Das erschließt sich mir nicht vollständig. Es kommt dabei eben stark darauf an, ob die Bezeichnung geläufig ist. Daher wäre das *rote Auto* oben sicherlich recht einfach einer gewissen Sportmarke zuzuordnen. Das *modernisierte* Hamburg ist zwar auch eindeutig, aber nur wegen des Eigennamens. Dann ist es letztendlich eine Stilfrage, ob man so tun will, als sei es ganz klar, dass *schön* ein unabdingbares Attribut ist, das nur manchmal weggelassen werden kann. In dieser Vorstellungswelt wäre *das hässliche Hamburg* also schon ein Widerspruch in sich. Ebenso wie die *neue Stadt* als *alt* zu bezeichnen im gegebenen Kontext unwilkürlich eine andere Stadt meinen muss, in dem Fall eindeutig die Alte Stadt. Daher ist ein einfacher Test auch, ob das Attribut alleine nominalisiert stehen kann. *Die Alte: schön modern*.

Das betrifft soweit grundlegendes Sprachverständnis, ist aber noch weit weg von Orthographie. Bei längeren Ketten hilft das erstmal wenig.